# $\sin(x) - \sqrt3 \sin(3x) + \sin(5x) < 0$ for $0<x<\pi$

Tags: trigonometry

My attempt at solving this:

$\sin(x) - \sqrt3\sin(3x) + \sin(5x) < 0$

$2\sin \left(\frac{5x+x}2\right) + \cos\left(\frac{5x-x}2\right) - \sqrt 3\sin(3x) < 0$

I divide everything with 2:

$\sin(3x) + \frac12\cos(2x) - \frac {\sqrt 3}2\sin(3x) < 0$

I think I have gone the wrong way at solving this problem. Please advise.

Comment: Strict inequality is not true. Just put $x=0$.

Comment: The book says that solutions are $\frac{\pi}{12}$, $\frac{\pi}{3}$, $\frac{2\pi}{3}$, $\frac{11\pi}{12}$

Comment: Why dos that make the function negative?

Comment: Write it as $$\sin(x) (2\cos(2x)+1)(2\cos(2x)-\sqrt 3)<0$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sin (x)+\sin (5x) - \sqrt3\sin(3x) <0\Rightarrow 2\sin(3x)\cos (2x) - \sqrt{3}\sin(3x) < 0 \\\Rightarrow \sin(3x)\left(\cos(2x) -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)<0 $$

Case $1$:

$$ \sin(3x) < 0 \text{ and } \cos (2x) > \frac{\sqrt3}2 \implies \frac{\pi}{12}<x<\frac\pi3$$

Case $2$:

$$ \sin (3x) > 0 \text{ and } \cos (2x) < \frac{\sqrt3}2 \implies \frac{2\pi}{3} <x< \frac{11\pi}{12}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$0>\sin x+\sin5x-\sqrt3\sin3x=2\sin3x\cos2x-\sqrt3\sin3x=2\sin2x(\cos2x-\cos30^\circ)$$

**Case**$\#1:$

If $\sin3x>0,0 <3x< 180^\circ$

we need $\cos2x<\cos30^\circ\implies360^\circ-30^\circ> 2x>30^\circ$

**Case**$\#2:$

What if $\sin3x<0?$

Comment: Sir, $\sin 3x$ ...

Comment: @Ak19, Thanks for your observation